# Storing Data from Multiple textboxes created dynamically

Tags: c#, textbox

I have used a button for creating a set of textboxes as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int a = 75;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, a);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);

            this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, a);
            this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
            this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox2.TabIndex = 0;
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);

            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(650, a);
            a += 25;
        }
  }
```

So there might be created many textbox1 and textbox2 for many button clicks. Say 10 textbox1 and 10 textbox2. How can I get data from all of them and to store in database. each textbox1 and textbox2 to be in a row of table?

Any help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I think you are looking for a `DataGrid`.

If not, there are several steps to be taken. First of all, `textbox1` and `textbox2` are members of the class and not the method, so with every click you edit the same TextBoxes again and again. To create new TextBoxes use

```
TextBox newBox = new TextBox();
```

inside the method and continue using it instead of `this.textbox1` (or `textbox2`). Keep in mind, that you should change to Location of the TextBoxes every time you click the button so that they don't overlap. You could use a class variable as click count.

I think the easiest way would be to store the created TextBoxes in a collection, for example a Dictionary:

```
public partial class...
{
    Dictionary<TextBox, TextBox> tbPairs = new Dictionary<TextBox, TextBox>();

    private void button1_Click(...)
    {

    ... //create newBox1 and newBox2

    tbPairs[newBox1] = newBox2;   //adds the Pair to the Dictionary
    }
}
```

To recall the content of the Dictionary after the TextBoxes are filled use

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<TextBox, TextBox> in tbPairs)  
{  
    ... //write to Server here - but that is an issue too big for handling here - look it up
}
```

For how to write Data to a database check out how to use `SqlCommand`s